# erfcinv from SymPy not workink with Julia

Tags: python, julia, sympy

I am running the following code in IJulia's Notebook:

```
using Sympy
z = Sym("z");
diff(erfcinv(z),z)
```

Yet, it yields:

`erfinv has no method matching erfinv(::Sym)`

`erfinv` doesn't work either. `erf`, `erfc`, and `erfi` **do** work. Moreover, if I run erfcinv(0.3), I get a numeric result.

In conclusion, for some reason Julia cannot differenciate `erfcinv` with symbolim expression, even though it is possible according to SymPy [code](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/_modules/sympy/functions/special/error_functions.html). I confirmed this since the above differentiation **does work** in python.

Comment: For future reference, it make much more sense to open an issue about a missing feature on the SymPy package repo than to post on SO about it: https://github.com/jverzani/SymPy.jl/issues.

Comment: I'm new to Julia so I didn't know that "method matching" indicates a missing feature. Will do in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks. This was an ommission. The current master now has `erfcinv` for symbolic values. (What you were finding was the built-in function from base.) If you find other missing features, please post an issue on the github site.

Comment: This might be a noob comment but the error still persist, even after updating packages via Pkg.update(). Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't push the changes to METADATA yet. To get this *right now* you could do `Pkg.checkout("SymPy")`. But for this particular problem, you might get by with just using an alternate syntax when a method is missing: `x[:erfcinv]()`.